# How can I switch radio button to yes or no without selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am writing a condition like:

```
if (dt > 0)
{
   objinvoice.editInvoice(strInvoice, strRenew, strExpiry);
   GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
   bindGrid();
}
```

I will have a radio button in gridview if that radiobutton is initially set to false and if the condition is true I would like to set it to true ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in gridview itemdatabound event.
You can check the condition and change the radiobutton status.

Gridview ItemDataBound example:

```
private void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Item.ItemType==System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType.EditItem)

RadioButton rBtnTest = e.Item.FindControl("radiobutton id") as RadioButton;
// Check condition and if it's true
if(your_condition == true)
 rBtnTest.Checked = true;
else
 rBtnTest.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: How can i save that in my database like if i checked=true i would like to save as Yes if not No

Comment: I don't understand your question Dorababu. Please repeat clearly.

Comment: suppose initially the radio button text will be false ... As per your given code it will set to Yes then how can i store it in my data base like if Yes radio button is selected i would like to change the No field to Yes